# Slick2D vs slick-util version/build confusion

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

[Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) officially seems to be split into:

- slick2D itself, the full 2D game library
- slick-util, a lightweight subset of slick2d, which only contains certain LWJGL helpers, e.g. for font rendering.

I'm currently trying to understand the versioning of both slick2D and slick-util.

One strange observation I made is that there are many references stating that slick-util is outdated:

- [LWJGL Wiki](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Slick-Util_Library_-_Part_3_-_TrueType_Fonts_for_LWJGL)
- [Slick Repo](https://bitbucket.org/kevglass/slick/issue/5/slick-util-is-fairly-outdated-and-there-is)
- [LWJGL Forum](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4654.0)

The essential point seems to be the situation regarding `TrueTypeFont` vs `UnicodeFont`: The above references mention that `TrueTypeFont` is deprecated and `UnicodeFont` is the appropriate successor; implying that slick-util is outdated since it does not contain the modern `UnicodeFont`.

My confusion continuous as a result of the following observations:

- Slick2D does not seem to have explicit version numbers; instead the `slick.jar` contains a `version` file which contains the build number. The current build seems to be 237.
- My project is currently using a `slick.jar`, which I downloaded about 2 years ago. Surprisingly this JAR has a build version 274 -- higher than the current version!
- The (apparently current) [Slick Repository Trunk](https://bitbucket.org/kevglass/slick/src/c0e4b96798d1c5b1969a26cb62eb7489d701ca6f/trunk/Slick/?at=default) reveals a build version 232 -- even lower than the current release!

My question is: Does Slick2D use a decreasing version numbering?

Further observation: I cannot find any deprecation warning regarding `TrueTypeFont` in the current source code itself. So the question is whether the claims that `TrueTypeFont` is deprecated (and slick-util is outdated) are actually true? Answering this question based on the file timestamps in the source archive does not seem to be possible: (Almost) all files in `slick-util-src.zip` have been updated in June 2013. So they have either all been updated (but there is still no `UnicodeFont` included in slick-util, but maybe `TrueTypeFont` has become the standard again!?) or they have simply be `touch`ed. Any clarification on what really is up-to-date here would be highly appreciated.